# How do I prove the set of the equivalence classes of $R$ has the same cardinality as the set of all finite sets of primes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Given the equivalence relation $R$ over $\mathbb{Z^+}: aRb \leftrightarrow \exists q \in \mathbb{Q}(\frac{a}{b} = q^2) $ how does one prove that the set of its equivalence classes $B$ has the same cardinality as the set of all finite sets of primes $C$.

What I am looking for, is some kind of proof that $B$ is a countable set.

I tried to come up with a mapping function between the two, compare them both to something else but everything was without any meaningful result. Any help is greatly appretiated.

Comment: What an odd way to phrase things.  There are countably many primes, hence countably many finite subsets of the primes, so you are just asked to prove that there are countably many equivalence classes for your relation, yes?

Comment: yes, i guess this really is a better way to ask this question ^^

Comment: @fmi21 It makes life much better for everyone if clarifications could be included in the question, not just in the comments. That means that people don't have to read all the comments to understand the question. It also means that you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: @almagest edited my post.

Comment: @lulu It's not an odd way to phrase it if you think about it in terms of a certain "natural" set of representatives.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Ah, that is true!

Comment: It would make the question comprehensible if you made explicit the set on which you are defining $R$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician it is Z+, im editing the post now

Comment: Notice that if $R$ is an equivalence relation on a set $X$, then $|X/R|\leq|X|$. So in your case, since $\mathbb Z^+$ is countable, $B$ can only be finite or countable infinite.

Comment: I find it odd that there are 3 close votes in this question, claiming that it doesn't meet MSE guideline. The question seems well posed and formatted, it's reasonable and not entirely obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be two positive square-free integers (i.e., $p^2$ doesn't divide $n$ or $m$, for any prime $p$), and suppose that $mRn$.

If $mRn$, then there exists a rational $q$ such that $\frac{m}{n}=q^2$.
Now, we may assume $q>0$, and this rational number can be written as $q = \frac{r}{s}$, where $r,s$ are positive integers and $\gcd(r,s)=1$.
So we have
$$
r = p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}
\quad\text{and}\quad
s = p_1^{\beta_1}\cdots p_k^{\beta_k},
$$
where $\alpha_i\beta_i=0$, that is, for each $I$, we can't have both $\alpha_i\neq0$ and $\beta_i\neq0$.
It follows that
$$ms^2=nr^2,$$
and so $r^2|m$ and $s^2|n$ (because $\gcd(r,s)=1$).
But then $p_i^{2\alpha_i}|m$ and $p_i^{2\beta_i}|n$.
Since $m$ and $n$ are square-free, it must be $\alpha_i = \beta_i =0$, for all $i$.
But that means $q=r=s=1$ and $m=n$.

So, if $m \neq n$ then they represent different classes.
Given that they are square-free, each number if fully determined by the (finite) set of primes that divide it.

---

**Edit.**
The reasoning above shows that each square-free positive integer is in a different class.
To finish the desired correspondence, one still has to prove that there are no other classes, i.e., that every $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ is related to some square-free one.
This follows from the fact that $nRnp^2$, for every prime $p$ and integer $n$.
Indeed, there exists $q \in \mathbb Q$ such that $\frac{np^2}{n}=q^2$: just take $q=p$.